# Search module in drupal 7

Tags: 7, search

I am using drupal 7 built in search module, when I searched for example `mechanics` it will filter out the results successfully but when I used to write only `mech` or `mechan` something like this, **it displays no results**.

For this I have installed [Apache Solr Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_autocomplete) and [Porter-Stemmer](https://www.drupal.org/project/porterstemmer) but I unable to figure out **how can I improve my search filtration**.

Comment: Are you interested in Autocomplete according to existing content in the site?

Comment: yes but is this possible if user search `mech` instead of `mechanics` then it should also shows results related to mechanics

Comment: Good question, if there isn't a module sounds to me like you would need to construct (or pay someone to construct) a module that crawls all the site for similar words, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the module  [**Fuzzy Search**](http://drupal.org/project/fuzzysearch) , this may solve your problem.

> This module provides drupal sites with a fuzzy search engine to allow
>   for broader keyword matches including partial or misspelled keywords.
>
> Fuzzy matching is implemented by using ngrams. Each word in a node is
>   split into 3 (default) letter lengths, so 'apple' gets indexed with 3
>   smaller strings 'app', 'ppl', 'ple'. The effect of this is that as
>   long as your search matches X percentage (administerable in the admin
>   settings) of the word the node will be pulled up in the results.

Comment: I have installed fuzzy search but now how can I configure it?or it automatically display results based on wild cards?

Comment: Carefully read the instruction on page where you have downloaded this module.